# Create a PHP contact form with multiple image upload

Tags: php, html, forms, upload, jpeg

I need to create an html contact form which collects some data and uploads 8 images through a PHP script

This is my HTML:

```
<form action="formmail.php" onsubmit="return controlloform()" id="form" name="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address" type="text" value="" maxlength="40">
    <input name="tel" id="tel" type="text" placeholder="Order number" value="" maxlength="20">
    <textarea name="msg" placeholder="Message" value="" maxlength="300"></textarea>
    Upload a photo:
    <p>
        <p>
            <input name="file" id="file" class="button" type="file" value="">
            <p>

                <p>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
</form>
```

I don't know how to create the upload script, what I need to do is uploading 2 blocks of 4 images, check the extension of the file (only jpg and png allowed) and the size (max 500 kb for image).

I've already found some upload scripts (not 100% suitable for what I need) but I don't know how to include the upload part into the rest of the code

If anyone could help me would be great

Thanks a lot

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to to make the multiple upload script and include it in the rest of the script (which collects other data such as name, address)

Answer (score 0):

This code make multiple upload

```
 $total = count($_FILES['photo_file']['name']);

    // Loop through each file
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
      //Get the temp file path
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['photo_file']['tmp_name'][$i];

      //Make sure we have a filepath
      if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['photo_file']['name'][$i];

        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

          //Handle other code here

        }
      }
    }
```

if you want to check file size insert this code

```
if ($_FILES["photo_file"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

this code make validation

```
$allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
$filename = $_FILES['photo_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how to include this part in the rest of my script?
Should I put it into my code or create a separate script?

My HTML form:
...

<form action="send.php" onsubmit="return controlloform()" id="form" method="post" name="form">

...

How can I make that module to send the data and upload the photos?

Comment: you can post the data to another page or post it to the same page and check if there is $_POST data so if there is it will execute the script

Comment: It's a contact form, all data should be into a single email

Comment: yea so you have to post the data to a page or the same page ? write ? at that point when you call the $_POST thats where you run the script

Comment: I don't understand :( ...perhaps it's because I'm quite ignorant (I just started to study PHP!) Where do I have to put the code ?